# 'Polly' object has no attribute 'start_speech_synthesis_task'

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-polly

I am trying to use [`StartSpeechSynthesisTask`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/API_StartSpeechSynthesisTask.html) of AWS Polly with this code:

```
client = boto3.client('polly')
response = client.start_speech_synthesis_task(
            OutputFormat= "mp3",
            Text = text,
            TextType = "ssml",
            VoiceId= VOICE, 
            OutputS3BucketName=BUCKET,
            OutputS3KeyPrefix=filename)
```

However, it throws this error:

> 'Polly' object has no attribute 'start_speech_synthesis_task'

I instantiated the client also with `boto3.Session(...).client(...)` – same error.

I tried updating boto3 to no avail. A [similar post in the AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=860609&tstart=0) seems unanswered.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. I have to instantiate with `region_name`:

```
client = boto3.Session(region_name='eu-west-2').client('polly')
```

Comment: I also had this issue but resolved by upgrading to botocore 1.12.0